# How to filter a list of tuples with another list of items

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have two lists: one list containing items which are reference numbers and a second list containing tuples which some include the reference numbers of the first list.

My list of reference numbers looks like this:

```
list1 = ['0101', '0202', '0303']
```

And my list of tuples like this:

```
list2 = [
('8578', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'),
('0101', 'ddd', 'eee', 'fff'),
('9743', 'ggg', 'hhh', 'iii'),
('2943', 'jjj', 'kkk', 'lll'),
('0202', 'mmm', 'nnn', 'ooo'),
('7293', 'ppp', 'qqq', 'rrr'),
('0303', 'sss', 'ttt', 'uuu'),
]
```

I want to filter the second list above depending on the presence of the reference numbers from the first list inside tuples: if the reference number is included in a tuple, the script takes it off from the list.

Here is the expected result:

```
newlist2 = [
('8578', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'),
('9743', 'ggg', 'hhh', 'iii'),
('2943', 'jjj', 'kkk', 'lll'),
('7293', 'ppp', 'qqq', 'rrr'),
]
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Show what you tried as properly formatted code in the question.

Comment: `newlist2 = [t for t in list2 if t[0] not in list1]`

Comment: Thank you @alaniwi

Comment: You should convert `list1` to a `set` to improve your performance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in [filter](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/filter-in-python/) function with a [lambda](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp):

`list2 = filter(lambda a:a[0] in list1, list2)`

This will turn list2 into a iterable, if you need it to be a list, not just an iterator, you can use a [list comprehension](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension) instead:

`list2 = [element for element in list2 if element[0] not in list1]`

Answer (score 1):

```
list1 = ['0101', '0202', '0303']
list2 = [
('8578', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'),
('0101', 'ddd', 'eee', 'fff'),
('9743', 'ggg', 'hhh', 'iii'),
('2943', 'jjj', 'kkk', 'lll'),
('0202', 'mmm', 'nnn', 'ooo'),
('7293', 'ppp', 'qqq', 'rrr'),
('0303', 'sss', 'ttt', 'uuu'),
]

filtered = []
for i in list2:
    if i[0] not in list1:
        filtered.append(i)


print(filtered)
```

output

```
[('8578', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'),
 ('9743', 'ggg', 'hhh', 'iii'),
 ('2943', 'jjj', 'kkk', 'lll'), 
('7293', 'ppp', 'qqq', 'rrr')]
```